# Display counter in a web page using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to display a counter on a web page who display all numbers one by one
I wrote this code, but it doesn't work, it displays only the last number

Can you help me? ChatGPT was useless :))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Compteur de 1 à 1000000</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="counter"></div>
<script>
    const counterElement = document.getElementById('counter');

    for (let i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        counterElement.innerHTML = i;
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Every iteration the loop completed, it just update to the content of counter element. Previous result are overwritten. How would you like to present the result?

Comment: You have to somehow _wait_ between every update to be able to _see_ it, so the easiest solution is wrapping it in an `async` function, adding a `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r,500))` right after updating your counter, and then calling the function,

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to make your code `async` by wrapping it in such a function and then adding a delay inside your `for` loop, like this:

```js
// `async` basically tells the engine that when it encounters `await` inside here,
// it needs to suspend the method. It also forces the return value to be
// a `Promise`, which you can, in turn, await itself if necessary.
async function counter(){

    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    
        counterElement.innerHTML = i;
        
        // The loop will be suspended until this promise resolves,
        // which will be in 100ms, as it awaits the completion of the timeout
        // the timeout calls the `resolve` callback, ending the timer
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout( r, 100 ));
        
    }
    
}

const counterElement = document.getElementById('counter');

// Since this is now async, we can hook into this as well
// When the counter has completed, we will print the text below.
counter().then(() => {
  
  counterElement.innerHTML = `Counter Complete`;
  
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-variant: numeric-tabs;
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you somethinghere, the goal was to show to student the speed at which the script goes into the loop. I reduced the delay to 1ms, it will works even if it will not show the exact reality

Comment: In that case another trick might be interesting: instead of a delay with timeout, use an animationframe! `new Promise( window.requestAnimationFrame )` will delay by exactly one frame, so you get to see every number at the fastest refresh rate?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely happening too fast for you to discern the counter. If you include a setTimeout (or something similar) you will see the numbers count up. Perhaps something like this:

```
const counterElement = document.getElementById('counter');

function delay(element, value, step, maxValue, duration) {
    if (value <= maxValue) {
        element.innerHTML = value;
        setTimeout(() => {
            value += step;
            delay(element, value, step, maxValue, duration);
        }, duration);
    }
}

delay(counterElement, 0, 10, 1000, 100);
```

Comment: This won't work, as every method is executed after 200ms, so after 200ms the 1000000 handlers will be called together, and just print `1000000` (the last one). If you want this to somewhat work, you should multiply the delay of 200ms times the index passed in, then every one happens with a spacing of 200ms from the previous timeout. Not the best way, as you create a lot of cruft up front, but it would work.

Comment: I tested this now and it "works" but not because of the reasons you think. It is limited by the precision of the timer callbacks, so it does get split up a tiny bit, but its not looping through every number, just the interval differences between the timer. This completes in like a second, for 1000000 iterations?

Comment: The previous way I was doing it had little or no control on the delay. Using recursion seems like a better solution, so I updated my answer.

Comment: This one does do the trick!